# How to make PyCharm show df columns in one line instead of splitting them?

Tags: pandas, pycharm

Is there a way to have PyCharm show all the columns in one line instead of splitting them?  For some reason it is only showing a few columns then splitting below with a '/', while there is a lot of white space that could be utilized.

[image]

[image]

Currently have pd option set for max columns, which does show all the columns, but wish I could see all the columns in one line. Maybe there is another option I can set, but seems this is likely a function of PyCharm.

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try `pd.set_option("large_repr", 0)` also. Check more details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) under the phrase *display.max_columns : int*.

Comment: Thanks, I looked through the documentation some more and found this option that worked for me:

    pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)